# How to add the new AdMob (google play services) as a jar instead of a library project?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I'm maintaining a generator of Apps that should depend only of jar library files. It must not depend of other projects. To depend of other project will need hard changes on this huge project, and will generate design and structural problems.

Now, in August, admob will stop working with his actual .jar file, and will need to be changed to the new Google Play Services project, that must be referenced in our project as a library project. How can i avoid this? How can i transform Google PLay Services project into a jard file that can be imported?

I tryed it creating a jar from the Google Play Services project, but then i get this error on this line of the manifest of my app:

```
         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

         Error: No resource found that matches the given name 
    (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove the meta-data from manifest because if you don't include the play services of course it raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i transform Google PLay Services project into a jard file that can be imported?

In general, you can't. If the AdMob code requires resources from the Play Services library project, that is Google's decision to make, and there is nothing much that you can do about it.

With respect to your immediate problem, you would need to somehow determine what `@integer/google_play_services_version` turns into, for any possible configuration, and replicate it in your project. This particular value is likely to be the same for all configurations, given that it is some sort of version number, though it does not have to be.

Long-term, you are either going to need to replace AdMob with something else that fits within your pigeonhole of an architecture, or you will need to support library projects. Considering that supporting library projects via Ant or Gradle involves one line in a configuration file (`project.properties` or `build.gradle`), one would think that this would not be a major challenge.